# How to trigger the lambda function only for INSERT event in dynamodb stream?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

How to trigger the lambda function only for `INSERT` event in dynamodb stream?

To reduce the cost of the lambda function, is it possible to trigger the lambda function based on the type of operation

1. INSERT - insert_lambda_function
2. MODIFY - update_lambda_function
3. REMOVE - delete_lambda_function

Comment: You would need to put code at the start of the Lambda function to determine whether or not to process the message. The function can then exit very quickly, probably only costing 100ms of usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible.